# How to install GeoFirestore with cocoapods?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, geofirestore

I have been struggling with installatin of https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-iOS 
with cocoapods but impossible to make it work. I got all sort of errors :
- framework not found FirebaseDatabase clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
- dependencies error

It seems that the repo is not maintened anymore. Is it still usable ?

Answer (score 0):

install pods with help of terminal

```
pod 'Geofirestore'
```

then in project setting make sure in LinkFrameWork and Libraries section firestore frameWork included.

Comment: sorry for this i mean from pods and than open .workspace project file inside the project directory not (.xcodeproj).